# Call method from class which extends Fragment

Tags: java, android, methods, android-fragments

I have `StartActivity` class. It extends from `Fragment`:

The code for `StarActivity.java` is shown below:

```
public class StartActivity extends Fragment {
    public static Context appContext;
    ActionBar actionbar;
    int state = 0;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }

    // call draw Tab method
    public void drawTab(){
          //ActionBar
        actionbar = getActivity().getActionBar();
        if(state == 0){
        actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        ActionBar.Tab PlayerTab = actionbar.newTab().setText("Fragment A");
        ActionBar.Tab StationsTab = actionbar.newTab().setText("Fragment B");

        Fragment PlayerFragment = new AFragment();
        Fragment StationsFragment = new BFragment();

        PlayerTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(PlayerFragment));
        StationsTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(StationsFragment));

        actionbar.addTab(PlayerTab);
        actionbar.addTab(StationsTab);
        state++;
        }
    }
```

In MainClass.java I declare a variable: `Fragment fragment1 = new StartActivity();`
How to I can call `drawTab` method. I try `fragment.drawTab` but it can't. If I call `drawTab` in `onCreateView` in `StartActivity.java,` it runs OK. but when I don't call `drawTab()` in onCreateView, error happens:(
RUN ERROR:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }
```

RUN OK:

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container,
                    false);
            drawTab();
            return rootView;
        }
```

MainClass.java

```
private void selectItem(int position) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), Integer.toString(position), 1).show();
        Fragment fragment1 = new StartActivity();
        switch (position) {
        case 5:
            break;
        case 1:
            ((StartActivity) fragment1).drawTab();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager1 = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager1.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment1).commit();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is when you create an instace of a fragment, it is not attached to the activity yet. So drawing a tab before onAttach method will cause a NPE error.

Try to do something below:

```
public class StartActivity extends Fragment {
    // TODO: add your other/current fields here
    boolean mDrawTabWhileInitializing = false;
    public StartActivity(boolean drawTabWhileInitializing) {
        mDrawTabWhileInitializing = drawTabWhileInitializing;
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);
        if(mDrawTabWhileInitializing) {
            drawTab();
        }
        return rootView;
    }    

    // TODO: add your other/current methods here
}
```

Use the boolean flag while initializing your fragment:

```
private void selectItem(int position) {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), Integer.toString(position), 1).show();
    Fragment fragment1 = null;
    switch (position) {
        case 1:
            fragment1 = new StartActivity(true);
            FragmentManager fragmentManager1 = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager1.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment1).commit();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

**Note:** Just an advice, the name of a fragment is annoying. Why don't you name it StartFragment?

Comment: If I call drawTab in onCreateView in StartActivity.java, it runs OK. but when I don't call drawTab() in onCreateView, error happens

Comment: No notification. Only ": E/(): Device disconnected: 1"

Comment: Have you tried putting ((StartActivity) fragment1).drawTab(); after replace (in your swithc-case statement)?

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work. I used `StartActivity fragment1 = new StartActivity();
fragment1.drawTab();` but it also doesn't work. I don't know reason

Comment: When I debug, watch "actionbar" variable error is: error during the evaluation

Comment: Your code also has errors. Each when I select it, tab is added. I only need 2 tabs

Comment: that's because of your drawTab() method. try to remove tabs before adding new ones.

Answer (score 0):

Declare it as StartActivity Fragment1 = new StartActivity();